# US citizen marrying UK citizen, planning to live in UK and work with US company

Tags: us-citizens

I'm a US Citizen, and work for a US company.  I'm engaged to a UK citizen and plan on moving to the UK.  My company is willing to keep me on, but I dont know what visa or work authorizations I need prior to my move.

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/partner-spouse? Will you be working remotely for your US employer or do they have a UK-based subsidiary that you would transfer to? https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/usa/work/longer_than_six_months

Comment: Thanks @Traveller I will be working remotely for my US employer.  I do think they might also have a UK based subsidiary.  My employer asked me to look into getting a work authorization based on my engagement to get me set up to work there post wedding but I couldn't find anything like that

Comment: IANAL but I think you first need to clarify the basis of your employment in the UK by your US employer and what, if any, visa that might qualify you for. If you come to the UK on a spouse visa, you are entitled to work straightaway. A fiancé(e) visa doesn’t give you the right to work until you have married and can switch to a spouse visa https://immigrationbarrister.co.uk/how-to-get-married-in-the-uk-choosing-the-right-visa-for-marriage/